# Org-mode list item spacing?

Tags: org-mode, faces

In org-mode, is it possible to increase the spacing between items in a list while keeping the line spacing in paragraphs the same? The closest I have found is to increase the height of `org-item-dt`, but that evidently increases the size of the bullet.

Comment: Which orgmode version do you use? On Emacs 24.5.1 I don't seem to have an `org-item-dt`.